# Visual Studio 2010 looks like Hot Dog Stand

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2010

This is what my Visual Studio 2010 window looks like. Obviously not ideal.

[image]

I used to have C# 2010 Express installed, all was fine, something happened, and then the colors went like this. I uninstalled everything, and installed a new copy of VS2010 Premium. The colors are still crazy.

I imported the .vssettings file from my work pc, but this only seems to have affected the editor window.

Any ideas how to get back to the default colors? (Resetting the settings via Import and Export Settings doesn't work, it just affects the editor window and the various things on the sides like Solution Explorer)

Comment: Have you checked for a virus?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I just use the Microsoft Security Essentials, and that's all up-to-date and not reporting anything. No other programs are like this, just Visual Studio. Seems a bit too specific for a virus, but I guess it's a possibility...

Comment: Attach the VS debugger to itself, and look in the Modules window for anything not by Microsoft.

Comment: Given that VS2010 is a WPF application, that might be something to look into. It might not be specific to VS2010.

Comment: @SLaks sorry, how's that done? What is the process called?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I've tried Expression Blend for Windows Phone (is that WPF?) and that looks fine. The only other WPF application I think I have is MetroTwit, and that looks fine too.

Comment: @GrahamClark I guess that rules out a generic WPF issue then :(

Comment: Open a second VS instance, Debug, Attach To Process, devenv.exe, then click Debug, Windows, Modules

Comment: @SLaks the only non-Microsoft thing in Modules is something called "MetadataViewProxies_[GUID]", with no path and no symbols loaded. I guess this is nothing..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorted now. Somehow I had a key in the Registry hive `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0` called `UseDebugColorScheme`. Deleted that, and the colors are back to normal.

Comment: Dang it, I was just getting ready to say that.  Did you have the Visual Studio color changing extension at some point?

Comment: hmm, that sounds familiar. Maybe!

Comment: It has a known issue that causes the rainbow if you don't set the color scheme back to default before removing the extension. Setting it to Default removes the UseDebugColorTheme key and another one that escapes me.

Comment: Please remember to mark your own answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg yep, no worries, but I'm not able to do that until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This link possibly speaks to your issue. At least it sounds like it.
 [Changing Visual Studio’s Color Palette](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/changing-visual-studios-color-palette/)
The link says that if you had installed the “visual studio color theme editor”

> Users who installed this extension for Beta 2 and customized the theme for VS2010 Beta 2 : If you have installed VS2010 RC on the same computer, you may experience a "rainbow colored" VS.

It may actually be the cause for some users of what was seen by the OP